# Parsing bytes (BCD, HEX, BIN) in dynamic sized file to C# entity object and vice versa

Tags: c#, parsing, binary, hex, entity

**Background:** *I am about to exhange data with a device that has been around for more than two decades, and the only supported way of exchanging data is by importing and exporting files that contains different types of records. I would have to support around 15-20 different types of file records, so I really hope to find a good solution to parse the data in and out of these files.*

The file records contains a lot of different data. The documentation states the following:

**Product File:**

| Field | Size | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ProductID | 4 Bytes | BCD |
| Record Size | 2 Bytes | HEX |
| StatusA | 2 Bytes | BIN |
| Price | 4 Bytes | BCD |
| Label 1 | 1 Byte | HEX |
| Label 2 | 1 Byte | HEX |
| ... | ... | ... |
| StatusB | 2 Bytes | BIN |
| 2nd Price | 4 Bytes | BCD |
| Sell By Date | 2 Bytes | 3 digits BCD, -no. of days |
| Sell By Time | 2 Bytes | 4 digits BCD, HH:MM |

*This is a subset of the documentation. The file contains much more information. But I am trying to make the question as simple as possible.*

The first three fields are mandatory. StatusA defines wether which fields are included or excluded in the record data.

Instead of I am trying to explain how to parse the file, let us just look at how we actually are to parse the file:

Let's take a look at the file:

`000000010016E001000199950105C00000024995001400000002000DC0000000499507000000300015C0010000109508A000000015950030`

I am not sure why, but for each byte the data contains two chars. So lets try to parse the three first fields: ProductID (4 bytes, 8 chars), Record Size (2 bytes, 4 chars) and StatusA (2 bytes, 4 chars)

`00000001|0016|E001|000199950105C00000024995001400000002000DC0000000499507000000300015C0010000109508A000000015950030`

What we get is: `ProductID = 00000001`, `Record Size = 0016` and `StatusA = E001` and when we parse the data to the right value based on it's type we get that:

| ProductID (DEC) | Record Size (DEC) | StatusA (Binary) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 1110 0000 0000 0001 |

Now we know that the record size for the first record is 22 bytes (44 chars). Here I am visualizing the record:

```
|         First record of 22 bytes           |
 000000010016E001000199950105C000000249950014 00000002000DC0000000499507000000300015C0010000109508A000000015950030
```

After the first record the second record comes, let's split the data into records:

```
|         First record of 22 bytes           | Second record of 13 bytes | Third record of 21 bytes                 | 
 000000010016E001000199950105C000000249950014 00000002000DC0000000499507  000000300015C0010000109508A000000015950030
```

Which gives us three records:

```
00000001|0016|E001|000199950105C000000249950014
00000002|000D|C000|0000499507
00000030|0015|C001|0000109508A000000015950030
```

That parses the first three fields to:

| ProductID (DEC) | Record Size (DEC) | StatusA (Binary) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 1110 0000 0000 0001 |
| 2 | 13 | 1100 0000 0000 0000 |
| 30 | 21 | 1100 0000 0000 0001 |

Now let's take a look at the StatusA of the first record where ProductID is 1. The bits in the StatusA states which data that is to come later in the data of the record. Let's transform the bits ´1110 0000 0000 0001´ into flags:

| Flag # | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Price | 1 = true |
| 2 | Label 1 | 1 = true |
| 3 | Label 2 | 1 = true |
| 4 | ... | 0 = false |
| ... | ... | 0 = false |
| 15 | ... | 0 = false |
| 16 | StatusB | 1 = true |

Based on these flags we now know that the next field in the data of the record is the price, 4 bytes (8 chars). The price is therefore `00019995` which is 19995 cents which makes it $199.95. The next two flags tells us the next two fields in the data is Label 1 (1 byte, 2 chars) `01` and Label 2 `05` (1 byte, 2 chars) that translates to 1 and 5.

Now there is some flags with the value of 0 = false, which means that the data does not have these fields included in its data. At last the flag for StatusB is 1 = true which means the data contains another set of flags for next part of data:

`00000001|0016|E001|00019995|01|05|C000|000249950014`

StatusB is `C000` that transforms to the bits `1100 0000 0000 0000` and the flags:

| Flag # | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2nd Price | 1 = true |
| 2 | Sell By Date | 1 = true |
| 3 | Sell By Time | 0 = false |
| ... | ... | 0 = false |

This tells us that 2nd Price and Sell By Date is included in the record of the data.

`00000001|0016|E001|00019995|01|05|C000|00024995|0014`

2nd Price is 24995 cents and Sell By Date is 14.

Now lets just fast forward to the end of all the parsing and have a look at the human readable records:

| ProductID | Price | Label 1 | Label 2 | 2nd Price | Sell By Date | Sell By Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 199.95 | 1 | 5 | 249.95 | 14 |  |
| 2 | 49.95 | 7 |  |  |  |  |
| 30 | 10.95 | 8 |  | 15.95 |  | 00:30 |

**The question:** What is a good way to parse these files? In the example above I would like to end up with an object entity that looks like this:

```cs
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public int? Label1 {get; set;}
    public int? Label2 {get; set;}
    public decimal? SecondPrice { get; set; }
    public int? SellByDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? SellByTime { get; set; }
}
```

I could be doing this with a lot of if-statements, but then I would have to do the exact same thing when writing entities back to the file again, in case we want to upload the changes to the device.

I have been thinking of using a custom attribute for each property and set some sort of flag pointer here, to be able to make the mapping. When writing back a property that is `null` the flag should be false and the data not be included. I am not sure if this would work or not.

I could also 'bite into the sour apple' (as we say in Denmark) and just spend a week implementing this the manually way with a lot of if-statements...

Have you ever done something similiar?

*I am sorry for the wall of texts, but I felt it was necessary to explain the whole problem.*

Comment: I would use Marshal techniques with structures so you just import files.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-classes-structures-and-unions?force_isolation=true#declaring-prototypes

Comment: @jdweng This was my first thought, too, but I doubt that this would be feasible if some of the fields might not be included in the data. We might end up with structures for different cases, but this would mean we'd have to skin throught the fields to determine the kind of the struct, which does not make the code easier. In the worst case we'd end up with n^2 strcutures for each and every possible combination.

Comment: That is really a different question.  There is a difference between parsing (importing) and optimizing the database.  I would put results into a database like SQL Server.  I usually like to start designing databases by using an excel spreadsheet to help me determine the number of tables and fields in each table.  Then once I get the design right I create the tables in a real database. I do not consider an excel spreadsheet a real database.

Comment: `FileHelpers` library is probably your best bet, you should be able to have optional fields

Comment: I would use a [Flags] Enum and I would loop to check which of them are actually flagged. Then dynamically I would read the property type that the flag mentions (probably with reflection) and based on each type (eg. Int32) I would read it/write it with System.BitConverter

Comment: You could also use custom annotation attribute to describe each property size (in bytes) if you can't do it with type eg. Int32

Comment: You could have a look at https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp

Comment: @WAKU MessagePack uses its own custom binary format incompatible with what the OP requires.

Comment: IMHO, this reminds me of over-engineering something similar once. I tried to come up with (de-)serialization controlling attributes - but the ultimately easier and more reasonable solution was to Keep-It-Stupid-Simple by implementing it conditionally. Chances are that the device is doing it just like that. You may just want to implement reusable methods to read/write primitives. You may want to create sub-structures for the flagged/nullable parts of the struct (like `class ProductStatusA`).

Comment: I used to develop a parsing library. It's template based: I use Python as the template language and function in the template file is a type (Like your HEX, BCD, etc.). The benefit using template-based parsing is it can give me most flexibility and every one can write a template after a short training, also I can handle complex parsing logic because Python is a programming language!

Comment: Other similar tool/library: https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/templates.html, http://kaitai.io/

Answer (score 2):

first I must apologize about my English. I've implemented a working solution, is not as generic or good as you expect (using attributes and this kind of thins) but is much better that doing everything by hand.

I've first made a parser which can read and convert a field of any type:

```
public class FileParser
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }

    public string Read(int len)
    {
        var ret = Content.Substring(Position, len * 2);
        Position += len * 2;
        return ret;
    }

    public int ParseIntBCD(int len)
    {
        return int.Parse(Read(len));
    }

   public int ParseHEX (int len)
    {
        return int.Parse(Read(len), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    }
}
```

Then I've made an abstract class that will be the base class for every type of record do you want to handle:

```
   public abstract class BaseRecord
    {
        public static T ReadRecord<T>(FileParser parser) where T: BaseRecord
        {
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            instance.FillFields(parser);
            return instance;
        }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public int StatusA { get; set; }

        public void FillFields(FileParser parser)
        {
            ProductId = parser.ParseIntBCD(4);
            Length = parser.ParseHEX(2);
            StatusA = parser.ParseBIN(2);
            InternalFillFields(parser);
        }

        public abstract void InternalFillFields(FileParser parser);
    }
```

It uses template method pattern to allow each subclass define its implementation of parsing the record.

Later, when I've tried to solve the Product class, I've noted that for the product some fields are not always read, so in the parse I've implemented a Conditional Parse method for each existing parse Method:

```
    public int? ConditionalParseIntBCD(int? status, int flag, int len)
    {
        return status.HasValue && (status.Value & flag) != 0 ? ParseIntBCD(len) : null;
    }

    public int? ConditionalParseHEX(int? status, int flag, int len)
    {
        return status.HasValue && (status.Value & flag) != 0 ? ParseHEX(len) : null;
    }
```

Then I could implement Product class as following:

```
public class Product : BaseRecord
{
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public int? Label1 { get; set; }
    public int? Label2 { get; set; }
    public int? StatusB { get; set; }
    public decimal? SecondPrice { get; set; }
    public int? SellByDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? SellByTime { get; set; }
    public override void InternalFillFields(FileParser parser)
    {
        Price = parser.ConditionalParseDecimalBCD(StatusA, 0x8000, 4, 2);
        Label1 = parser.ConditionalParseHEX(StatusA, 0x4000, 1);
        Label2 = parser.ConditionalParseHEX(StatusA, 0x2000, 1);
        StatusB = parser.ConditionalParseBIN(StatusA, 0x0001, 2);
        SecondPrice = parser.ConditionalParseDecimalBCD(StatusB, 0x8000, 4, 2);
        SellByDate = parser.ConditionalParseIntBCD(StatusB, 0x4000, 2);
        SellByTime = parser.ConditionalParseTimeSpan(StatusB, 0x2000);
    }
}
```

And as last step, I've added this method to File Parser

```
    public bool EOF { get { return Position >= Content.Length; } }

    public IList<T> Decode<T>(string file) where T : BaseRecord
    {
        Content = file;
        Position = 0;
        var l = new List<T>();
        while (!EOF)
            l.Add(BaseRecord.ReadRecord<T>(this));
        return l;
    }
```

As you can see solution is not so elegant as using attributes and a generic solution, but once you define the needed parse functions each Record definition is really easy and clean.

I've implemented the needed code to test the example you has made Successfully and upload it to GitHub in the following repository: [Example Repository](https://github.com/pablorevert/stackoverflow-1)

This example it's only intended to explain my solution, it does not has any error handling and if file format is not correct it will fail, but I understand that will be useful to start working if you like my solution.

Please let me know if it works!

---

**Edit**

In order to do the opposite direction, you will need to implement some method to encode the fields, for example:

```
    public string EncodeIntBcd(int len, int? value)
    {
        return value.HasValue
            ? value.Value.ToString().PadLeft(len * 2, '0')
            : "";
    }
```

Then make for each class it corresponding encoding method:

```
        public override string InternalEncodeFields(FileParser parser)
    {
        var ret = "";

        ret += parser.EncodeBin(flag1 = Price.HasValue, flag2 = Label1.HasValue, flag3 = Label2.HasValue, flag16 = StatusB.HasValue);
        ret += parser.EncodeDecimalBcd(4, 2, Price);
        ret += parser.EncodeHex(0x8000, 1, Label1);
        ret += parser.EncodeHex(0x8000, 1, Label2);
        ret += parser.EncodeBin(flag1 = SecondPrice.HasValue, flag2 = SellByDate.HasValue, flag3 = SellByTime.HasValue);
        ret += parser.EncodeDecimalBcd(4, 2, SecondPrice);
        ret += parser.EncodeIntBcd(2, SellByDate);
        ret += parser.EncodeTimeSpan(SellByTime);

        return ret;
    }
```

(*) Please note that for StatusA and StatusB I've not used its current value, I calculate this at the moment of record generation. That way you don't need to assign them a value manually.
(**) Also notice that StatusA is implemented in Product and not in BaseRecord. That is because its value  depends on the specific properties of Prodyct Class

Then, in the BaseRecord class you would have something like this:

```
   public string EncodeFields(FileParser parser)
    {
        var r = InternalEncodeFields(parser);
        var len = (r.Length / 2) + 6; //4 of ProductId + 2 of Length
        r = parser.EncodeIntBcd(4, ProductId) + parser.EncodeHex(2, len) + r;
        return r;
    }

    public abstract string InternalEncodeFields(FileParser parser);
```

And in FileParser implementation will looks like:

```
    public string Encode<T>(IList<T> records) where T:BaseRecord
    {
        string file = "";
        foreach (var r in records)
            file += r.EncodeFields(this);
        return file;
    }
```

I've left unimplemented this second part of the answer, but I understand that if you understand the first part, doing the second one will be easy.